# How can we convert a value from TPenstyle to string

Tags: delphi

How we can convert a value from `TpenStyle` to `string`?

Comment: See also [how-to-get-enumeration-type-into-stringlist](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1897771/576719).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of [converting an enumeration to a string](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip0103_5.htm).